# PostgreSQL Invalid Value for Parameter Warning

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL 8.4.3, I get this error when logging on to one of my databases (adus):

```
WARNING:  invalid value for parameter "default_text_search_config": "tsc_markets"
```

which makes sense since executing the command `\dF` does not list any such configuration (and only lists the defaults).  However, when I ask psql to show me the current value:

```
adus=# show default_text_search_config;
```

I get

```
 default_text_search_config
----------------------------
 pg_catalog.english
(1 row)
```

In addition, the `postgresql.config` file has the entry:

```
# default configuration for text search
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

plus, there is only one (user) defined schema that I use (also called adus) in this database.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL allows you to associate configuration settings with databases and roles (users), so check there too: look at the `pg_database` and `pg_roles` rows for the database you are connecting to and the user you are connecting as, and see if `default_text_search_config` is being set there. You can remove the configuration setting with the syntax:

```
alter database db reset default_text_search_config
alter role username reset default_text_search_config
```

You're seeing the default value from "show", since it fell back to that after failing to set one of the overridden values.